# Firebase: How flat should my data structure be?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an app that tracks the user's location and updates Firebase. I've read the documentation about structure data but still have a few questions.

I'm considering structuring the data in one of two ways, but can't determine which one.

```
users
  $id 
    -position
    -other attr
```

vs:

```
user_position
  $id

users
  $id
    -other attr.
```

In what scenario would the first design work best, second?

Comment: @philipxy I would disagree. Either design could provide positional coordinates. for example 2:  The path of user 0 is  */rootref/27_6N-82_2W/uid_0* and tomorrow will be */rootref/30_5N-77_7W/uid_0*. Then a query for uid_0 would reveal their coordinates in the keys returned. In general though, there's no real way to answer this question as a Firebase is structured to accomodate the type of queries being done and what data is needed. Perhaps updating the question with more info would help us to understand the use case.

Comment: If you are considering this choice, *what procedure are you following that you are stuck with*? If you aren't following a guide to design (not to be confused with a programming/product manual that tells you how to express things relevant to implementing a design) then find some intro(s) to information modeling & database design & follow until you are stuck.

Comment: @Jay Got it, thanks.

Comment: @philipxy I guess what I'm mainly struggling with is whether its more straining to observe two nodes (nested) with smaller data tree per query (ie. second option) or to observe one node, with a slightly larger data tree.

Comment: Observers are pretty light weight so the 'strain' would be negligible in either case. However - the amount of child data can affect that but we don't know how much child data you're talking about so there's really no way to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only keep one position per user (as seems to be the case by the fact that you use singular `user_position`), there is no useful difference between the two structures. A user's position in that case is just another attribute, just one that happens to have two value (lat and lon).

But if you want to keep multiple positions per user, then your first structure is mixing entity types: users and user_positions. This is an anti-pattern when it comes to Firebase Database.

The two most common reasons are:

- Say you want to show a list of user names (or any specific, single-value attribute). With the first structure you will also need to read the list of all positions of all users, just to get the list of names. With the second structure, you just read the user's attributes. If that is still much more data than you need, consider also keeping a list of `/user_names` for optimal read performance.
- Many developers end up wanting different access rules for the user positions and the other user attributes. In the first structure that is only possible by pushing the read permission from the top `/users` down to lower in the tree. In the second structure, you can just give separate permissions to `/users` and `/user_positions`.